# Firefox WebExtensions: how to restore a zombie tab (to get it's real URL)

Tags: javascript, firefox, tabs, firefox-addon-webextensions

Right now if you ask for a `tab.url` of a zombie tab in FireFox, you will always get `about:blank`. I need the real URL, the one that will be loaded when you select the tab and it reloads.

How do I accomplish this? I have tried a `browser.tabs.reload(id)`, but it just reloads the `about:blank`, even when I bypass the cache. Ideally, this wouldn't require actually reloading the tab (it was zombified for a reason), but right now I'll take anything.

I'm trying to do this from a `background.js` script, with the `tabs` permission, but I'm open to adding more permissions/different script types if necessary.

Thanks.